# Push notification alert doesn't show

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, xcode11

In my app I cant see a system modal with agreement for push notifications. Im going to update my app for ios. Since one week (at begin of may all worked fine) after update xcode to newest version my app isn't asking about push notification (ios alert doesn't show). In capatibilities I still have 'push notification'.

Code for push notification (capacitor + reactJS) didn't change. Also I downloaded files from begin of may from git but when I ran app from xcode alert didn't show.

From plugin I am getting only token for in app push probably (I cant send normal push by this key)

Does anybody have this problem ?

Comment: I assume, that you did delete/reinstall application and the push notifications are not ariving, right?

Comment: Yes, i tried to remove capatibility „push notification” and add again. I also tried uninstall app, reboot phone, install again. I also installed app on new iPhone (never installed my app) and it doesnt work too :/

Comment: Did you take a look at their(apple) docs about explicitly asking for the permissions? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/asking_permission_to_use_notifications

Comment: We are using capacitor - reactjs. Should i look in capacitor files after compile files ?